# AngularJS Controller window Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a problem with my angularjs App with a window function.

For example, a window resize function.

It should only be used in the controller/template it's in. But the function (someFunction()) in the controller gets triggered on every site.

Here is the code:

```
angular.module('app.site').controller('SiteController', SiteController);         

function SiteController($scope, $document, $window) {
angular.element($window).bind('resize', function () {
    someFunction();
});
...
```

Route:

```
.state('app.site', {
                url: "/site/edit/:id",
                templateUrl: "Scripts/modules/site/site-edit.tpl.html",
                controller: 'SiteController',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to bind and unbind it like so :

```
var someFunction = function () {
  // Do something 
};

angular.element($window).on('resize', someFunction);

scope.$on('$destroy', function () {

  angular.element($window).off('resize', someFunction);
});
```